# Ambiguous method signature in ExpressJS. How to solve it?

Tags: express

I have two url signature

```
var userView = '/um/rest/queryview/:queryType/:queryRef'
var userDetail = '/um/rest/queryview/queryRef/:queryRef'

app.get(userView, function(req,res){console.log("userView")});
app.get(userDetail, function(req,res){console.log("user detail")});
```

If I fire http://localhost:8080/um/rest/queryview/queryRef/BH3RHM... the output turns out to be "userView" and not "user detail".

If I block the userView exposure /*app.get(userView)...*/ then it works fine.

What is the best way to define the urls and it's methods then?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the order of the routes. 
Instead of:

```
app.get(userView, function(req,res){console.log("userView")});
app.get(userDetail, function(req,res){console.log("user detail")});
```

You can do this:

```
app.get(userDetail, function(req,res){console.log("user detail")});
app.get(userView, function(req,res){console.log("userView")});
```

This way express will try to match the `userDetail` url first, then try to match the `userView` url.